# Is it a good practice and safe way to create user defined function with mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Am trying to change my project from mysql to mysqli. I have my db connection as:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Opps! Connection could not be established: ", mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
```

Then I have a user defined function as:

```
function get_name($id) {
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "select name from staff where id='$id'");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    return $data = $result['name'];
}
```

I understand that I have to declare $link as global (as shown below) which work fine.

```
function get_name($id) {
    global $link;
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "select name from staff where id='$id'");
    $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    return $data = $result['name'];
}
```

My question here is: Is it a good practice and is it safe?

Comment: Don't use globals. They are bad practice and cause issues when trying to debug. With procedural functions, you'd want to pass the $link as an argument:  `get_name($link, $id)`.  However,  you should research OOP (object oriented programming) and classes if you want to learn a good way of doing things.

Comment: How you share the database handle is only relevant for adding or avoiding code complexity. More interesting would be utilizing bound parameters, for a function that might as well be used with user input. (Also, mysqli isn't widely favoured precisely for that. Read up on PDO before investing too much time.)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't necessarily call it a good or bad practice to write a function with such a specific purpose, just what fits your needs. If you plan to do this exact task in multiple places throughout your code, a function is useful to make your code easier to read and avoid repeating yourself.

As far as safety goes, you need to sanitize inputs before using them in a query. For the case of an integer `$id` field, you could simply cast it as an integer `$id = (int)$id;`. For other data types, you would want to escape it by using `$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $id);`. Then you'll be safe.

I would also advise that you look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of mysqli. I believe it's much more commonly used these days.

Comment: Happy with the PDO advice. With regards to sanitizing the user input, I do that before any function call.

Answer (score 1):

Taken literally, this question makes very little sense. User-defined functions almost always are good practice, no matter if you are using them with mysqli or any other API. Yet functions in general have nothing to do with safety.

While speaking of the code provided, it is not safe because of lack of **prepared tatements**.

So, to make your code proper, **you have to create functions to handle mysqli queries with parameters first**. And then employ these functions in your own helper functions, to make them look like this:

```
function get_name($id) {
    return dbgetOne("select name from staff where id=?",[$id]);
}
```

as you can see it will not only make your queries safe, but also shorten your code.